# Footnotes repeated erroneously in Beamer (when compiled with notes)

Tags: beamer, footnotes

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Why are \protect\emph{we}\footnote[frame]{The Steering Council} here?}
    \note{A few presenter's notes.}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item We are looking for \emph{new ways} to ...
\pause      \item We search for strategies, which ...
\pause      \item The Steering Council is the body that coordinates ...
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Works as expected, until I uncomment the option to show notes on the second screen:

[image]

Can anybody explain?